# How to create the replica set only for specific collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I created MongoDB replica set. It works perfectly fine. But, how do I create the replica set only for specific collections?

> Business Case: We have many collections with lots of writes going on
>   but it can be volatile, i.e. we don't need to replicate all these
>   large collections. We just need replication/failsafe only for one
>   collection.

Is this possible?

Comment: The only database that is not replicated in a replicaset is 'local'. Other databases will replicate. This is not a standard practice but still you can move collections, that you don't want to replicate, to 'local' database and leave everything that you want to replicate in their own database.